# How to make a sticky button for an item in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with expandable items, each item having a list of its own. I want a  particular button to be sticky on the item while scrolling, like the `Apply for selected shifts` button in the image given below.

[image: image example of]

Comment: whats a "sitcky button" and where is it located on the image you're showing? all those buttons look regular to me.

Comment: a sticky button is a button that stays at a fixed position while scrolling. the apply button should be sticky

Comment: "What have you tried so far" ?

Comment: using an item decorator but its not the same feeling cuz all it does is draw over and its not a clickable view :/

Comment: Do you mean a floating action button?

Answer (score -1):

```
<RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:padding="16dp"
        tools:context=".fragments.TestFragment">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/Id_btn"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/Id_recyc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/Id_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="test"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This will place the button at the bottom of the screen irrespective of the length of the recyclerview.The button will stick to its place as you desire hope it helps

Comment: every item should have its own button, suppose you have two items expanded both of them should have the apply button

Comment: you can easily add the button inside the adapter class just add the button in the adapter's xml and you can do what you desire inside the onBindViewHolder so that each and every items will have its own button